# RuntimeError: ERROR Mrelation "tablename" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, rails-postgresql, pg

Rails - 2.3.8
Database - Postgres(9.2)

Active record query is not able to generate tablename in double quotes ie

```
   # this ran fine
      Table.find_by_sql('Select * from "Table" Limit 1')

      Sql generated -    Select * from "Table" Limit 1
```

But issue comes in,

```
      Table.find(:first)
      Sql generated -    Select * from Table Limit 1 (Clearly noticed that table not in double quotes)
```

Active record displaying error

```
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: RuntimeError: ERROR
  C42P01  Mrelation "Table" does not exist 
  P15 Fparse_relation.c L864    
  RparserOpenTable: SELECT * FROM Table  LIMIT 1
```

I feel that postgresql adapter is not able to generate tablename in double quotes.

Comment: Would need to see your model definition and migration in order to determine what's going on in your query. I use the postgres adapter daily, and I have not had any problems with quotation of table names.

Comment: I am facing this problem for each and every model. When I try writing those queries in my rails console. It give me error for every model.

Comment: Isn't 'table' a reserved word in postgres?, Wouldn't you need to encase it in quotes if so?

Comment: Sorry I would have specified it. It is just table name.

Answer (score -1):

I never get a chance to work on Postgres. But I have a workaround solution for this. Try as follows:

```
table_name = '"Table"'
table_name.find(:first)
```

I haven't try this in my machine since I do not have the required setup. I hope it should work.